# Adding an lxml library to project

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I'm writing a small project in Python that parses XML files to JSON.
It uses a lxml library (need to use XMLParser that can recover XML files).

The problem is that I need to deliver my project as runnable out-of-box. lxml is not standard Python library, so I need to include it with my script. The script should be runnable from Linux Debian 9 or Windows Server.

Is it possible to deliver working library with my script? 
lxml needs to be compiled to work and it depends on system, it also needs libxml2 and libxslt libraries to work on Windows.

Thanks,
Szymon

Comment: Did you find an easy solution?

Answer (score 2):

Check PyInstaller
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

> PyInstaller bundles a Python application and all its dependencies into a single package. The user can run the packaged app without installing a Python interpreter or any modules.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something similar to Google AppEngine's solution for third party libraries, just put the module in a "lib" subfolder, then programatically add it to the python path.  Here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27), which was written for Python 2.7, but the concept is still valid.